# Disable SwitchInput blue glow in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, bootstrap-switch, shinywidgets

How to disable the blue glow that appears over a `switchInput` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following CSS tag to your UI.r file or UI section of your Shiny app:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-focused {
                                  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
                                  border-color: #CCCCCC;
                                  box-shadow: none;
                                  outline: none;
                                  }'))),
```

This will disable the blue glow and change the outline color to gray.